# liquibase creates duplicate sequence IDs in postgresql database

Tags: duplicates, sequence, liquibase, postgresql-9.5

i am an amateur with postgresql and a newbie with liquibase.
i am using puppet and liquibase to create postgresql database on rhel server.
i drop the database (puppet resource postgresql_database  ensure=absent) then run puppet to re-create the database.

i log into psql and run \dt \di \ds.  no duplicate tables or indexes but duplicate sequences e.g. 
activity_log_activities_id_seq
activity_log_activities_id_seq1

the baseline.xml lists the sequence 1 time e.g.

```
<createSequence sequenceName="activity_log_activities_id_seq"/>
<createSequence sequenceName="activity_log_activity_products_id_seq"/>
```

i've google'd liquibase duplicate sequences id1 etc. but no good hits.
please advise.

Comment: Works fine for me. Which Liquibase version are you using? Can you post the complete changelog file? What happens if you run the changelog directly with Liquibase, not through puppet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we didn't figure out what was creating the sequences the 1st time but we did resolve it via removing the creation of the sequences within the baseline.xml included.
now i'm attempting to figure out why when i add includeAll with path="sqls" and run java -jar ../liquibase.jar  --changeLogFile=master.xml update
it comes back with "Liquibase Update Successful"
but it's not making a change to the database or the databasechangelog table.  i'll do a search and see if it's already been answered elsewhere...  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if You have defined Your primary key as **serial** then it's not required to generate db sequence by ddl

```
--create sequence IF NOT EXISTS study_study_key_seq start with 1 increment by 1;  
create table IF NOT EXISTS study (study_key serial not null, create_sysdate TIMESTAMP without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null, modify_sysdate TIMESTAMP without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, study_id varchar(120) not null, primary key (study_key));
```